# android- Intentional '%' in string throws IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, encoding, utf-8, illegalargumentexception

I am making a http call to an api for a string response.
The result contains intentional % signs in a sentence like:
"This land is 95% fertail and 5% contaminated"

Android throws IllegalArgumentException: Invalid % sequence at 1756 which corresponds to the "95%" part.

**EDIT**: StackTrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid % sequence at 1756: [{"address":{"addressComponen...
```

My httpGet method:

```
public String makeHttpGetRequestUtf8(String urlStr) throws IOException {
    String result = "";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        BufferedReader brIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = brIn.readLine()) != null)
            result += line;
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("HTT_GET", "Failed to make httpGetRequestUtf8: " + e);
    }
    String afterDecode = URLDecoder.decode(result, "UTF-8");
    return afterDecode;
}
```

Android throws IllegalArgumentException: Invalid % sequence at 1756 which corresponds to the "95%" part.

Server writes this data with this metod and so I believe the encoding should be fine?

```
    File file = new File(path/filename.txt);    
    String content = writeMeToFile;
    Writer out;
    try{
        out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF8"));
        if(!file.exists()){
            file.createNewFile();
        }else{
            FileUtils.copyFile(file, dest);
            out.write(content);
            out.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(UpdateAds.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }
```

Side question/note: Somehow characters like 'ä', 'ö', 'ü', 'õ' are fine in the browser but show up as � in android.

I don't understand at which side am I encoding the string wrong. Since the text is fine in the browser I am thinking it's android, but the httpGet method is done *by the book*.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, do you mean the error stacktrace or something from the server side?

Comment: yes on androidstudio

Comment: Added the stacktrace.

Comment: can you share with me your api link

Comment: Sorry not quite ready for public posting but maybe I could send it to you personally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110644/discussion-between-ravi-and-kaspartr).